# [Oracle.DataAccess.Client]how to determin whether a oracle connection is not used?

Tags: c#, oracle

According to the Oracle documentation, The **Connection Lifetime** parameter in the connectstring is checked when the application close a connection and return back to the connection pool.My question is that **only when Close() or Dispose() method of connection is invoked, the Connection Lifetime will be checked?**

The doc says that every 3 minutes, the connection pool service will check the connections and see if they are used. It will destory the unused connections every run accoring to the **Decr Pool Size** parameter. **so how to determine a connection is not used? Will it check the lifetime of the connection ?**

Looking forward to the reply if anyone knows the situation.

here i wrote some codes to test, it seems that a connection is always valid and will never be destroyed after 3 minutes.

```
OracleDaoBase emdwDao = new OracleDaoBase(@"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxx)(PORT = 1521)))
                (CONNECT_DATA =
                    (SERVICE_NAME = xxxx)
                )
            ); User ID=xxx;password=xxx;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=1;Incr Pool Size=1;");
            int cnt = 0;
            while (cnt < 10)
            {
                cnt++;
                var requestTime = DateTime.Now;
                // open the connection
                var dbConnection = emdwDao.GetConnection();
                Console.WriteLine("The cost of gaining a connection："+(DateTime.Now - requestTime).TotalMilliseconds +"ms");
                // sleep 3 minutes and 5 seconds
                Thread.Sleep(1000*60*5 + 5* 1000);
                // return to the connection pool
                emdwDao.CloseConnection(dbConnection);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
```